How to build a basic app on Kivy using python?
import kivy
kivy.require('2.3.0') # replace with your current kivy version !

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label


class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return Label(text='Hello world')

I am trying to run the above code (MyApp.run()) but it's failing with OSError: source code not available error. Any idea how to resolve it ?

The question title is too board, did you follow the installation tutorial in here, and try pong game tutorial, if you still encounter, please include the error message in a code block in the post.

Add the line:
MyApp().run()

to the bottom of your python file. Then run:
python main.py

(Assuming that your python file is named main.py)
